# Genymotion error - VirtualBox DHCP server has not assigned an IP address to the virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have been trying to get an Android emulator running for a few weeks now with no luck.  I first tried Xamarin Android Player and couldn't get it to work, so I decided to try Genymotion.

I installed a few virtual devices and get the same error for all.
Error: The device got no IP address. The virtualBox server has not assigned an IP address to the virtual device.

I tried several things that I found online (including stack overflow):

1. I have an AMD processor, so I ensured "Secure Virtual Machine Mode" was enabled in the BIOS
2. I uninstalled/reinstalled both VirtualBox and Genymotion
3. Ensured "Promiscuous Mode" was set to "Allow VMs" under the VirtualBox network settings
4. In VirtualBox opened Host Network Manager - deleted it, restarted and re-tryed.
5. Completely Disabled my Firewall
6. I ensured the Host Network Manager  settings were correct.  See screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

Id I attempt to run it directly from VirtualBox, I get an error that says "eth0 is not configured correctly - HARDWARE OPENGL IS DISABLED !!!"

This is what the settings look like in VirtualBox:

[image]

Comment: I have same issue but only with Oreo virtual devices. Having old AMD Phenom II processor.

Comment: I have same problem! still no help!

Comment: Reinstalled virtual box. Then issue fixed.

Answer (score 18):

start VirtualBox ,RightClick on Intended device,click start then Click normal start  normal wait for window shows up,after seeing IP Management on that window,start Genymotion then start intended device.

dont forget do not close window.

Comment: This helped me a lot; this was the only way I could get them to consistently start up. In order to prevent having a useless window stuck around, you can choose "Detachable Start" instead of "Normal Start." Once you see the IP assigned in the VirtualBox window, you then start the device in Genymotion. Once it connects, back in VirtualBox you can select Machine -> Detach GUI to get rid of the useless window.